# How to get the string value in NFC tag on flutter?

Tags: flutter, nfc

I'm new in flutter and I'm using nfc_manager package try to read NFC ntag 215 card, after I tap the NFC tag I got this output

NFC output

[image: 1]

I have 2 problem now:

First, I only need this part of the output : payload: [2, 101, 110, 116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103], how can I only get this part of value on flutter?

Second, after I get this specify part of the output, I know this should be ASCII codes data, but how can I decrypt it to a string value on flutter?

here is my flutter code to read the NFC:

```
//ref https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager/example
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';

class NFC_scanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const NFC_scanner({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<NFC_scanner> {
  ValueNotifier<dynamic> result = ValueNotifier(null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('NfcManager Plugin Example')),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
            future: NfcManager.instance.isAvailable(),
            builder: (context, ss) => ss.data != true
                ? Center(child: Text('NfcManager.isAvailable(): ${ss.data}'))
                : Flex(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: ValueListenableBuilder<dynamic>(
                              valueListenable: result,
                              builder: (context, value, _) =>
                                  Text('${value ?? ''}'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: GridView.count(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          childAspectRatio: 4,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                          children: [
                            ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text('Tag Read'), onPressed: _tagRead),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _tagRead() async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(content: Text('You can tap the tag now !'));
        });
    try {
      await NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
        result.value = tag.data;
        print('tag.data: ${tag.data}');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      result.value = e.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

I found a method to decrypt the ASCII data `String str = String.fromCharCodes([2, 101, ...]);` but I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: Is the output a JSON? You can parse it to get payload (refer https://codewithandrea.com/articles/parse-json-dart/)

Comment: I thought it not json but I'm wrong, thanks you bro, I know what I should I do now

Answer (score 1):

First of all your need to access that payload value. Then convert that payload into charCodes into string. For that use the code below:

```
    // To access payload 
NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered : (NfcTag tag) async{
var payload = tag.data["ndef"]["cachedMessage]["record"][0]["payload"];
// now convert that payload into string
var stringPayload = String.fromCharCodes(payload);
}
```